# Why does the email-password example work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Taking my first steps with Firebase. Just a few pointers to documents explaining what is going on will help.

I have set up a new firebase web project and connected my dev environment with the firebase sdk. Now when I drop the [email-password quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/acbb46f441ac7c216730bc07b7371354702a7000/auth/email-password.html) into the project it works. (after enabling email/password sign in.)

But wait: This quickstart html file does not contain any configuration that the firebase console tells me to paste:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.xxx.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.xxx.com",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.xxx.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
  };
```

Does the local firebase server add the configuration in the background? When and where do I have to add this configuration to web pages?

Answer (score 1):

If you check [line 35 of that quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/acbb46f441ac7c216730bc07b7371354702a7000/auth/email-password.html#L35), you'll find this magic include:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

This is an auto-generated file by Firebase Hosting, that contains precisely the code that initializes the connection to the Firebase backend services of your project.

If you'd like to learn more about it, read:

- [Easier configuration for Firebase on the web](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html)
- [SDK imports and automatic initialization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#sdk_imports_and_implicit_initialization)
- [SDK auto-configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration)